Python program runs fine in terminal but will not run in windows scheduled task
I'm trying to figure out why my python script will not run in Windows Task Manager. I've scheduled many tasks including even tasks that restart windows, but this problem has me baffled. Here is the part of my python script from the beginning to where it stops running:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime
import os
from pathlib import Path
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as sql
import inspect
import requests
import configparser
import re
import time
import math
from io import StringIO
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

logstuff = dict()
logstuff['Duplicity'] = 1
logstuff['basename'] = Path(__file__).stem

def GetLogFile():
    global logstuff
    LogFileName = os.environ['TEMP'] + '\\TWCO'
    if not os.path.exists(LogFileName):
        os.mkdir(LogFileName)
    # print("In function: logstuff[basename]=" + logstuff['basename'])
    if 'basename' in logstuff.keys():
        LogFileName = LogFileName + "\\" + logstuff['basename'] + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".log"
    else:
        LogFileName = LogFileName + "\\" + Path(__file__).stem + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".log"
    SALog = open(LogFileName, "w")
    SALog.write("Python program " + Path(__file__).stem + " starting...\n")
    logstuff['FileNumber'] = SALog
    logstuff['FileName'] = LogFileName
    return logstuff

def logsomething(logstring):
    global logstuff
    output = (datetime.datetime.now()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " " + logstring
    if logstuff['FileNumber']:
        logstuff["FileNumber"].write(output + "\n")
        if logstuff['Duplicity'] == 1:
            print(output)
    else:
        print(output)

def ChangeDate(Date):
    return datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime(Date, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"), "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S")

def MakeBigInt(MyVar):
    if isinstance(MyVar, float):
        if math.isnan(MyVar):
            return 0
        else:
            return int(MyVar)
    else:
        return int(MyVar)

def MakeString(MyVar):
    if isinstance(MyVar, (float, int)):
        if math.isnan(MyVar):
            return ""
        else:
            return str(MyVar)
    if isinstance(MyVar, str):
        return MyVar
    
def MakeFloat(MyVar):
    return float(MyVar)
    
start_time = time.time()

# os.system('cls')
ComputerName = os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']
ScriptName = str(Path(__file__))

GetLogFile()

logsomething("Reading the configuration files.")
config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=None)
logsomething("Loaded ConfigParser")
config.read("//pri-lvm-na01/export_five9/Util/Five9CredsSA.ini")
logsomething("Opened Five9CredsSA.ini")
Five9Username = config['Communications']['Five9UserName']
logsomething("Five9 User Name: " + Five9Username)
Five9Password = config['Communications']['Five9Password']
logsomething("Five9 Password (don't tell anyone): " + Five9Password)

My log file prints "Opened Five9CredsSA.ini" and then nothing more. The task ends with a result of 0x1. I have made sure that the "start in" folder in task scheduler points to where my code is; I have tried setting the task to run as admin (run with highest privileges) and also in user mode. I have re-installed Python 3.12 in "all users" mode (after removing the one in my appdata folder) and re-installed all the admin mode so that they exist for everyone. I must be missing something as I have searched the internet multiple times and all the recommendations don't seem to work for me. I believe it is a problem relating to configparser since that's where it stops running, but I don't see any errors in a log file that I tried to create. The batch file that I run is:
echo Running Program > Five9INRRpt.log
"C:/Program Files/Python312/python.exe" c:/Software/Py/Five9INRRpt.py >> Five9INRRpt.log

And the output is this:
Python program Five9INRRpt starting...
2024-12-16 19:55:37 Reading the configuration files.
2024-12-16 19:55:37 Loaded ConfigParser
2024-12-16 19:55:40 Opened Five9CredsSA.ini

So it is apparently able to open the configuration file but when it tries to read it it errors out. The computer that I'm running this on is running Windows 11 Enterprise as the Operating System.
Thanks a bunch!

what do you get when you run from command prompt instead of scheduled batch file?

Try to specify the entire path to your config
config.read("C:/pri-lvm-na01/export_five9/Util/Five9CredsSA.ini")
It probably crashes due to a key error on the  config['Communications']['Five9UserName'] operation because it can't read the configuration with the path passed in.
You can check this by splitting the configuration read
communications = config['Communications']
logsomething(f"communications: {communications}")
Five9Username = communications['Five9UserName']

I think the program could be encountering KeyError when trying to read config['Communications']['Five9UserName'] from config. Have you tried printing out the config using something like logsomething(str({s:dict(config.items(s)) for s in config.sections()})) after config.read("//pri-lvm-na01/export_five9/Util/Five9CredsSA.ini") to make sure Communications section exists and has Five9UserName

config.read() will NOT throw an exception if it can't open the file, it just does nothing.  So the log message Opened Five9CredsSA.ini is misleading.  Maybe it opened the file, or maybe not...

Im putting in my 2cents that when script is executed via task schedular, it does not have permission to read network share which //pri-lvm-na01/export_five9/ indicates where the file is. So, what others have said, are probably correct but the cause is windows security...

@syncended I think you pointed me in the right direction. When running in task scheduler the result of your test came back as {} but when running it in the terminal it worked fine and gave me the contents of my file. It appears to be a file access issue. I will work from there and post a solution if I figure it out. Thank you!
